# $L^p$-norm diverges for a sequence of functions

Tags: convergence-divergence, solution-verification, lp-spaces, sequence-of-function

> Let $\{f_n \}_n$ real valued functions such that:
> \begin{cases}
> f_n \geq 0 \\
> \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n =1\\
> \forall \delta >0: \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty } \int_{|t|>\delta}f_n(t)dt = 0
> \end{cases}
> Show that, for every $p>1$:
> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty} ||f_n||_{L^p} = +\infty \quad \star$$

---

First I note that $1 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(t)dt = \int_{|t|<\delta}f_n(t)dt + \int_{|t|>\delta} f_n(t)dt$
and taking the limit follows that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{|t|<\delta}f_n(t)dt=1$$

Now, in order to prove $\star$, I would like to show that for every $M>0$, there exists a $\bar{n} \in \mathbb{N}$  such that for every $n>\bar{n}$: $||f_n||_{L^p}^p>M^p$.

Therefore, since $f_n \geq 0$:

$$\int_\mathbb{R} f_n^p = \int_{|t|<\delta} f_n^p + \int_{|t|>\delta} f_n^p$$

Now I choose $\delta$ such that for $t \in \{t: |t|>\delta \}$ I have $f(t)<1$, therefore the second integral goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Also, since for $t \in \{t: |t|<\delta \}$ it holds that $f_n(t)>1$, and $f_n \geq 0$, it follows that $f_n^p>f_n$ for evry $p>1$.

So I can write $\int_{|t|<\delta}f_n^p > \int_{|t|<\delta}f_n$ and since the last term is $1$ as $n \rightarrow + \infty$, I have that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{|t|<\delta}f_n^p = 1 + \varepsilon_p$$ with $\varepsilon_p >0$

I don't know if it's okay up to now, but in any case I don't know how to conclude. Can anyone help me?

Comment: $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{|t|<\delta}f_n(t)dt=1$ is wrong. It should be $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{|t|<\delta}f_n(t)dt=0$.

Comment: Yes it was a typo. I have fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Holder's inequality. $\int_{|t|<\delta} f_n(x)dx \leq \int (f_n^{p}(x)dx)^{1/p} (2\delta)^{1/q}$ where $\frac 1 p +\frac  1 q=1$. The conclusion follows easily from this since $\delta$ is arbitrary.

Comment: thanks, but I don't know how to move now... I mean, how do you use this fact in the proof?

Comment: You already know the the left side of my inequality tends to $1$. Hence $\lim \inf \int f_n^{p} \geq \frac  1 {(2\delta)^{p/q}}$. Now let $\delta \to 0$.